# rtl wordpress site width is ridiculously large

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, right-to-left

site: tibbiyat.com

if you test it using your mobile (less than 600 px) the extra width is not there

I also tested it in ltr direction, no extra width!

so I wiped out the whole rtl.css file, still the same problem

I tested another 2 themes, one of them was responsive, neither had the problem.

**edit**: If it's relevant in anyway: I removed the translation file (ar.mo), same probelm.

here's the css file: http://jsfiddle.net/me0x27pr/

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
#page {
width: 85%;
}
}
```

btw, there's a reset.css file too: http://jsfiddle.net/x9dny4q5/

Answer (score 0):

finally, fixed!!
here's the code:

```
#expound-social a span {
left:auto;  right: -9999px;
}
```

as a side note: don't forget to zero/auto a property, don't forget properties like left/right and text indents

Answer (score 0):

I think this also will help you:

```
html{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```